# instantiating a class object (template) from a base class

Tags: c++

> ```
> Warning newby
> Base class trying to instantiate template class
> Rather than put all the code in , I'll try excerpts for brevity
> Base class constructor has error: Trying to create an object of template class Queue. 
> There is a typedef setting data_type = Card (a
> common class).
> ```

```
    DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards()
    {
        Queue<data_type>* deck;
        deck = new Queue<data_type>;
        fill_deck(deck&);   **"error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token"**
    }
```

> ```
> **fill_deck declaration:**
> ```
>
> from the header :     void fill_deck(const Queue<data_type>& data);

```
void  DeckOfCards::fill_deck( const Queue<data_type>& deck)
{
    for (int i=0; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
       for (int j=1; j< 14 ; j++)
       {
          if ( j == 11 ) {
             cardID = "J" + suits[i];
             cardValue = 10;
          } else
          if ( j == 12 ) {
             cardID = "Q" + suits[i];
             cardValue = 10;
          } else
          if ( j == 13 ) {
             cardID = "K" + suits[i];
             cardValue = 10;
          } else {
             cardID = suits[i] + IntToString(j);
             cardValue = j;
          }
       cardFacing = false;
       Card* cardPtr  = new Card(cardID,cardValue, cardFacing);
       deck.enqueue(cardPtr&); **"error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token"**
       delete cardPtr;
       }
    }
    cout << "\nFinished add " ;
}
```

> ```
> Method enqueue from Template Queue:
> ```

```
template <class data_type>
    void Queue<data_type>::enqueue(const data_type& data){
    qList->addToTail(data);
    length++;
}
```

> The plan was to create a Queue class object and populate that queue
> with type Card another class. I couldn't Pass a reference parameter to
> the function DeckOfCards::fill_deck() and I couldn't refer to the new
> Queue object.
>
> ```
> Any help appreciated
> ```

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by using `new` to create the object in your constructor, only to completely discard it, and not store it anywhere, so the only thing that this accomplishes is a huge memory leak? C++ is not Java.

Comment: That's some excessive formatting, you should use quotes only for real quotes and code blocks only for code not for text. It just overloads your question and makes it hard to read. See also our [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

`fill_deck` accepts a reference `const Queue<data_type>&` so since you created a pointer

```
Queue<data_type>* deck;
deck = new Queue<data_type>;
```

you'd dereference it to call `fill_deck`

```
fill_deck(*deck);
```

similar problem later, which should be

```
deck.enqueue(*cardPtr);
```

As a general note, you have a lot of `new` allocations that likely could instead be stack allocated. You're likely leaking memory by doing so, though it is hard to say without seeing the context of the rest of the class design.